# How to remove hardcoded characters from playlists?

Tags: php, theme-development, customization, javascript, audio

I'm working on a Wordpress theme for a website that makes heavy use of its default media player. In the process of styling its playlists, I found that a core file injects hardcoded characters that can't be made invisible just by using CSS, so I'm a bit clueless about how to hide/remove them.

These characters are injected on 3 different places on each playlist entry:

1. those entries are numbered, but the container is a div instead of an ol, so using list-style-type: none is not possible;
2. they add curly quotes to the song title, but not by using :before and :after;
3. and they add an em dash before the artist name, also not by using the :before pseudo-class.

On wordpress\wp-includes\js\media.php there's a function called **wp_underscore_playlist_templates** which declares the following script:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-item">
<div class="wp-playlist-item">
    <a class="wp-playlist-caption" href="{{ data.src }}">
        {{ data.index ? ( data.index + '. ' ) : '' }}
        <# if ( data.caption ) { #>
            {{ data.caption }}
        <# } else { #>
            <span class="wp-playlist-item-title"><?php
                /* translators: playlist item title */
                printf( _x( '&#8220;%s&#8221;', 'playlist item title' ), '{{{ data.title }}}' );
            ?></span>
            <# if ( data.artists && data.meta.artist ) { #>
            <span class="wp-playlist-item-artist"> &mdash; {{ data.meta.artist }}</span>
            <# } #>
        <# } #>
    </a>
    <# if ( data.meta.length_formatted ) { #>
    <div class="wp-playlist-item-length">{{ data.meta.length_formatted }}</div>
    <# } #>
</div>
</script>
```

Of course I could edit this core file, but I don't want to do that. So what should I do? Add a filter on functions.php? Make a JS file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the shortcode function for playlists, there is this line:

```
do_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', $atts['type'], $atts['style'] );
```

Hooked into that is `wp_playlist_scripts()` which hooks the templates into the footer:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
```

So if you want to replace the templates, you can hook into `wp_playlist_scripts` *after* those hooks have been added (so any priority greater than 10), remove the hooks, then hook in your own templates:

```
function wpse_296966_hook_new_playlist_templates() {
    // Unhook default templates.
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );

    // Hook in new templates.
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_296966_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse_296966_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
}
add_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', 'wpse_296966_hook_new_playlist_templates', 20 );
```

Then you just need to copy the `wp_underscore_playlist_templates()` function, in its entirety, to a new function in your theme/plugin called `wpse_296966_underscore_playlist_templates()` (or whatever you want, just needs to match the `add_action()` call. Then make any modifications you want to the function to get the markup you wanted.

I would avoid doing anything *too* drastic though, since the scripts likely depend on specific classes, and the general structure. But removing these unwanted characters shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I should only note the function you wrote above is already called `wpse_296966_hook_new_playlist_templates()`, so the other new function needed a different name to prevent an error.

Comment: I did give it a different name.

Comment: True, my bad. I did something wrong, got a conflict error, renamed it and everything went fine.

Answer (score 2):

For the **title** in question *"they add curly quotes to the song title, but not by using :before and :after;"* and other kind of templates **using gettext calls**, you can filter the javascript templates like this in your functions.php:

```
add_filter('gettext_with_context', function($translated, $text, $context, $domain){
    if($context = 'playlist item title' && $text == '&#8220;%s&#8221;') $translated = "%s";
    return $translated;
}, 10, 4);
```

Remark the filter name, its differ from context `_x(` calls vs `__(` calls.

/If someone struggles with same issues

Comment: Nice - this works for getting rid of the curly quotes if that's all you need to do. I ended up going with the full template override because I also wanted to target the track number (`{{ data.index ? ( data.index + '. ' ) : '' }}`). Pretty sad that element for the index is not wrapped in a span so we could target it with CSS.